# I can't display the firebase auth exceptions in my flutter app

Tags: flutter, dart

Everything works fine,i can smoothly create a user but i'm stuck on displaying the signup exceptions on my app.

Please check what is missing  my code

```
    class MyEmail extends StatefulWidget {
     @override
     State<MyEmail> createState() => _MyEmailState(nameController);
    }

   class _MyEmailState extends State<MyEmail> {
   String errorMessage = '';
   ...

    @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return GestureDetector(
    ..
          Form(
              key: _regFormKey,   
                Container(
                  margin: EdgeInsets.all(20),
                  child: TextFormField(
                    controller: _emailController,
                    focusNode: _focusEmail,
                    validator: (value) => Validator.validateEmail(
                      email: value,
                    ),
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                      hintText: "Email",
                  ),
                ),
                ), // end of form
                   Center(
                  child: Text(
                 errorMessage,
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.red),
               ),
               ),

           ...
      }
```

Here is my button

```
RaisedButton(
              onPressed: () async {
                if (_regFormKey.currentState!.validate()) {
                  setState(() {
                    _isProcessing = true;
                  });

                  try {
                    User? user = await FireAuth.registerUsingEmailPassword(
                      name: nameController,
                      email: _emailController.text,
                      password: _passwordController.text,
                    );
                    setState(() {
                      _isProcessing = false;
                    });
                    errorMessage = '';

                    if (user != null) {
                      Navigator.of(context).pushAndRemoveUntil(
                        MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => ProfilePage(user: user),
                        ),
                        ModalRoute.withName('/'),
                      );
                    }
                  } on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) {
                    errorMessage = error.message!;
                  }
                 
                }
              },
             
              child: const Text(
                'Continue',
                style: TextStyle(color: Colors.white, fontSize: 20),
              ),
            ),
```

I'm using the string errorMessage to carry the auth exceptions that are later supposed to be displayed before the continue button.
The exceptions are shown on my IDE output but the problem is displaying them on the app

Everything else on creating the user works just fine .

Answer (score 1):

Instead of

`on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) { errorMessage = error.message!; }`

Use

```
on FirebaseAuthException catch (error) { setState(() { errorMessage = error.message!; }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

Use SnackBar to show error messages.

```
 ScaffoldMessenger.of(context).showSnackBar(SnackBar(
          content: Text('${errorMessage}'),
          backgroundColor: Colors.red,
        ));
```